# How do I validate agree terms checkbox for woocommerce registration form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, checkbox, woocommerce

I have stmbled into a bit of a problem with the woocommerce registration form. I wanted to add a agree to the terms checkbox that would actually work.

I added the code that shows the checkbox in form-login.php (from the templates/my account folder).

I tried to modify the code in wc-user-functions.php and class-wc-form-handler.php from includes folder and now it does not recognize when the user checks the box. It gives me the Please accept terms error every time regardless if i check the box or not.

Does anyone know where is my mistake?

form-login.php added code

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="accept_terms" class="inline"><span class="required"></span></label>
            <input name="accept_terms" type="checkbox" id="accept_terms" value="empty";/> 
            <?php _e( 'Am citit si sunt de acord cu' ); ?> <a href="<?php echo "http://................." ?>"><?php _e( 'termenii si conditiile', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        </p>
```

wc-user-functions.php added code

```
// Check the accept terms
if ( empty( $accept_terms ) )  {
    return new WP_Error( 'registration-error-accept-terms', __( 'Please accept terms', 'woocommerce' ) );
}
```

wc-class-form-handler.php modified code

```
public static function process_registration() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['register'] ) && isset( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'woocommerce-register' ) ) {
        $username = 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
        $password = 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
        $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $accept_terms = $_POST['accept_terms'];

        try {
            $validation_error = new WP_Error();
            $validation_error = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', $validation_error, $username, $password, $email, $accept_terms);

            if ( $validation_error->get_error_code() ) {
                throw new Exception( $validation_error->get_error_message() );
            }

            // Anti-spam trap
            if ( ! empty( $_POST['email_2'] ) ) {
                throw new Exception( __( 'Anti-spam field was filled in.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            }

            $new_customer = wc_create_new_customer( sanitize_email( $email ), wc_clean( $username ), $password);

            if ( is_wp_error( $new_customer ) ) {
                throw new Exception( $new_customer->get_error_message() );
            }

            if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_auth_new_customer', true, $new_customer ) ) {
                wc_set_customer_auth_cookie( $new_customer );
            }

            wp_safe_redirect( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) );
            exit;

        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . __( 'Error', 'woocommerce' ) . ':</strong> ' . $e->getMessage(), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why you need to modify wc-class-form-handler.php and wc-user-functions.php, override the templates and all other things should be done in functions.php or with a custom plugin ?

Comment: If you set a Terms and Conditions page in the Checkout settings, WooCommerce automatically adds and validates it. Checkout prevented if terms are not accepted. You shouldn't need to modify anything.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu well, I'm really new to wordpress, php or coding of all sorts. I tried to make a custom form with contact form 7 plugin but don't know how to give it the functions that the woocommerce registration form has. What you see above is the closest that I came to what I need to achieve.

Comment: @helgatheviking Well I did that, but I want to also have a terms and conditions checkbox in the My account page. If the user registers an account through my account page I don't have the option through woocommerce platform to set an agree to terms checkbox on the register form from my account page

Comment: I would suggest you to learn coding, before doing this type of job, you have listened wordpress/woocommerce are too easy, but the fact is those people have never did it correctly and never able to solve any problem, so please spend some time on learning.why you need contact form 7 on woocoomerce , if you need extra fields and validation, you can customize this using hook .

Comment: Prafulla, I think user is here to learn some coding. :)

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I am trying to learn. I have been googling this for the past week, but with no luck. I have found how different people implemented php forms with validation, but none seem to work. I have also checked to see if there are any plugins for this and found 2, one of which is reported not to work and the other modifes only the form on wp-login.php which I do not want. I will try to find more about hooks and figure out what to write in functions.php Thanks for the tips

Comment: @helgatheviking I have seen you a lot during my learning and you are very good, I appreciate you but, you know stack is not the site to learn for non-coders .

Comment: @user5444543 I hope you will spend some time at least in http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php,  wordpress codex  and woocommerce codex in near future .

Comment: @user5444543 I have no idea what I got or not got , I spend my 3 years on PHP manual and more than a year in wordpress codex and some months in woocommerce codex , and I would love to spend more .

Comment: Guys, I'm really sorry for asking stupid questions. Didn't realize this site is dedicated mainly to people who know code.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Thanks for your kind words. SO is a site for coding questions, but there's no minimum barrier to entry. There's no aptitude test to be considered a "coder". Believe me, I get hella annoyed by all the terrible questions that straight up look like people wanting free work, but this is a pretty clear question statement with some obvious attempts to work out the solution himself.

Comment: @helgatheviking then the right way to guide him is , he should not modify core files and then , notice what is the problem, so that should be answered .so that, that will not be a workaround .

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not edit core WooCommerce files. You will lock yourself into the code and never be able to update, which is bad. And there's really no need and WooCommerce is littered with hooks and filters which permit you to make modifications from your own themes/plugins. The following should go in your theme's `functions.php` or preferably into its own custom plugin.

This first part will add the terms checkbox. If you wish to show the exact same terms field as on the checkout page, then you can just use the same template.

```
function so_33122634_add_field_to_registration(){
    wc_get_template( 'checkout/terms.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'so_33122634_add_field_to_registration' );
```

Then on the `woocommerce_process_registration_errors` we can check the `$_POST` and throw exceptions if it isn't there. WooCommerce will collect all the exceptions and show the appropriate error messages.

```
function so_33122634_validation_registration( $errors, $username, $password, $email ){
    if ( empty( $_POST['terms'] ) ) {
        throw new Exception( __( 'You must accept the terms and conditions in order to register.', 'text-domain' ) );
    }
    return $errors;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_registration_errors', 'so_33122634_validation_registration', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: @helgaviking Thank you so much. I will try to see if I can make it work. Regarding the core files. I have saved a copy of the files I have edited, just in case.